# Symfony2 change the value field of template twig

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, controller

I am developing an application reservation and when the user selects an hour to book and save it in the database the value that is saved is the position of the radio button , this is my controller:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($reserva)
            ->add('horaReserva', 'choice', [
                'choices'=> $horasDisponibles,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                ]
            )
```

So I pick up in the template:

```
 {{ form_widget(form.horaReserva, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

And this is what shows the web:

```
<input type="radio" id="form_horaReserva_0" name="form[horaReserva]" value="0">

<label for="form_horaReserva_0" class="required">9:00</label>
```

The fact is that when stored in the database saves me as 0, would there be any way to change the field value from the controller and the template for the value field has the value of the hour?

Comment: What is the value of `$horasDisponibles` in your example ?

Comment: $horasDisponibles = array(
            '9:00',
            '10:00',
            '11:00',
            '12:00'
        );

Comment: Ok, what's the symfony version you're using ?

Comment: I 'm using the version 2.5.4

Comment: Ok and what model format would you like to get back from the field, the string `"9:00"` or a `DateTime` object ?